# Dockerfile wildcards not working for COPY command to copy folders

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a folder structure as below:

```
Folder
    |- folder1.framework
        |- bin/...
        |- <other files/folders>
    |- folder2.tests
        |- bin/...
        |- <other files/folders>
    |- folder3.tests
        |- bin/...
        |- <other files/folders>
    |- Dockerfile
```

I want to copy just the files/folders in bin directory that is part of all .tests subfolders when building the docker image. In my dockerfile I have this line:

```
COPY **tests/bin/ /app
```

But I get an error saying "no source files were specified". For some reason wildcards are not working in copy command. I even tried:

```
COPY *.tests/bin/ /app
COPY **.tests/bin/ /app
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you running docker on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You will need to use ADD instead of COPY:</strike>

`ADD *.tests/bin/ /app`

docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Sorry, COPY also just works fine, I tried it:

`COPY *.tests/bin/ /app`

So please share your Dockerfile and logs that your docker build is producing, also docker version, os version just in case.